# Error while running python file

Tags: python3

```
(base) C:\Users\Admin>activate RR-1722-stage1

(RR-1722-stage1) C:\Users\Admin>pip -m pip install --upgrade pip

Usage:
  pip <command> [options]

no such option: -m

(RR-1722-stage1) C:\Users\Admin>cd dektop
The system cannot find the path specified.

(RR-1722-stage1) C:\Users\Admin>cd desktop

(RR-1722-stage1) C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>cd eyanta
The system cannot find the path specified.

(RR-1722-stage1) C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>cd eyantra

(RR-1722-stage1) C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\eyantra>cd 2. Test Setup

(RR-1722-stage1) C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\eyantra\2. Test Setup>python test_task0.
py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_task0.py", line 29, in <module>
    import task0_cardinal
ImportError: bad magic number in 'task0_cardinal': b'B\r\r\n'

(RR-1722-stage1) C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\eyantra\2. Test Setup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```bsh
python -m pip install --no-cache --upgrade pip
```

If you want to use `pip` directly, you can use the following command:

```bsh
pip install --no-cache --upgrade pip
```

the `-m` is used for "run library module as a script"

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `--no-cache` should be `--no-cache-dir`. That said, there is likely little reason to run `pip` with this option on Windows (unless you are really intent on saving disk space). `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` is the official Python recommended way of upgrading `pip` on that platform.

Comment: `--no-cache` means to dowload a new time without trust the previous downloaded package

Comment: Ah. I wasn't able to find a reference to that option in the general [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/) or [pip install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/) docs. There is, however, `--no-cache-dir`, which is used to `[...]disable the cache and always access PyPI[.]` That is the only reason I mentioned it. But poking around, it does seem like either option will work.